# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint in SSMS import/export wizard

Tags: sql-server

I have table MYTABLE with one PK constraint, generated by a third-party app:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [FIELD_A] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [FIELD_B] [tinyint] NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT [mytable_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY],
  UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( [FIELD_A] ASC ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And the data is pretty simple:

```
ID  FIELD_A     FIELD_B
1   abc         0
2   dfgh        0
3   foo         0
```

I'm trying to import this data into an empty copy (created with generate scripts wizard/above ddl) of this table in another database using data import, but get the following error:

```
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'mytable_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.mytable'"
```

I have tried the following (to verify this isn't a duplicate question):

- Check that there is no actual duplicate in the destination: The destination is empty
- Enabled option "Enable identity insert" (if disabled, this fails with `Violation of FOREIGN KEY...` instead)
- Attempted with both 'Delete existing rows' and 'Append'
- Disabled constraint checking: `EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'`
- Attempted to not import the surrogate ID - this fails as import wizard sets field to `null` if ignored instead of leaving empty.
- Checked for triggers that may be creating duplicate inserts
- Forced SSMS to just drop and recreate the tables

What else can I check to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you removed IDENTITY attribute on the second table?

Comment: @McNets Do you mean create the blank table without `IDENTITY (1,1)` and add it back later, or try and choose not to import the ID field?

Comment: IMHO you should never add an IDENTITY column to the destination table, unless you are using transactional replication and you have flagged it as NOT FOR  REPLICATION.

Comment: Thanks @McNets, do you know if this type of thing is something I can specify in the create scripts wizard? I rely on the script creation as I need to do this for about 150 tables.

Comment: Why don't use transactional replication? I think it worth for a volume of 150 tables.

Comment: I will look into replication - I unfortunately need to go between different SQL server versions (downgrade...) and I'm not sure the built-in replication will allow it.

Comment: Replication allow for some cross-version scenarios. But is all depends on what versions and what type of replication (transactional, merge, snapshot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bug(?) with using the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` for both the data source and destination. I changed the data source to use the `OLE DB Driver for SQL Server` instead, and it worked normally using Enable ID insert.

For reference, my situation was:

- Two instances of SQL Server, 2017 and 2019
- A dirty version downgrade of this DB from 2019 to 2017

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem also.  It turned out that I had a case sensitive collating sequence (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) on the source column and a case insensitive one (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) on the target.  Change the target fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start by narrowing it down. Does it happen with only this one table? What if you play around with the scripting options (still only doing this one table); uncheck "everything". Etc. Until you have something working and then add bits and pieces back on until you find which one breaks it.

In the end, this is either a problem in the wizard (since duplicates cannot occur in the source data when you have a unique index), or we don't have the full story (hence my recommendation to narrow it down).

If it is a problem in the wizard, then consider reporting it to MS. They will likely want a repro for your problem.

Comment: Yes it seems to be mostly a process issue, but I'm really looking for specific recommendations. It's not just this one table - I'm currently trying different connection types since this does seem like buggy behavior.

Comment: I was about to ask for the bigger picture and recommend backup/restore, but I just read your comment on downgrade. But without a repro for us, you are really looking for someone who ran into that very same issue, I guess. I haven't, I'm afraid... (?). :-)

Comment: Or cheat and change the DDL to IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON